# Different versions of war files using eclipse and maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a mavenized web project which generates the war file. When I deploy this war file to the tomcat, it works fine. However, when I use eclipse to run the project on tomcat, it packages a different set of jars in the war and the deployment is unsuccessful. Would you have any pointers on how to get the same war file generated using eclipse as the one that i get using maven?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
Right click on project 
click on run as
click on run on server
set tomcat as your new runtime
then run
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thats what I am doing. But the deployment fails because the war file being generated is adding some extra set of jars which dont get added when i do a maven install. Any ideas?